# ELAN touchpad: Software to turn left button or any key into middle button?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, mouse-buttons, acer-travelmate

I joined the throngs migrating away from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro and bought an [Acer TravelMat P2](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/professional-model/NX.VGTAA.006):

- Model name: TMP2410-G2-M-55HN
- Part number: NX.VGTAA.006

It has an ELAN touchpad and driver, so there's no point trying to install Synaptics (which is perilous anyway, if it doesn't already come installed).

**Is there any software that will turn the left button into a middle mouse button?**

The Windows 10 customization only lets a 3-finger tap act as a click of the middle button.  It does not provide a means for clicking, holding, and dragging.

**Update: Is there software that allows *any* key to act as the middle mouse button?**

Comment: This question is best suited on this subsite https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK, I posted it there.  I'm just wondering, is it inappropriate for it to be on this site too?

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: In case you don’t get any answer, try editing your question to make it more interesting.

Comment: I can think of AutoHotKey that might help you. Try using it.

Comment: Thanks, Vijay.  The site even has a forum section.

Comment: It’s “Valay” but never-mind. Also, did you get the answer?

Comment: Sorry, Valay.  If by "answer", you mean did I try AutoHotKey, no, not yet.  I haven't even had a chance to post there yet.

Comment: Nah not about the autohotkey but did you get the solution to your problem?

Comment: No...I don't really have dedicated time to focus on it, so I try what I can as time permits.  This may take a while, but the info is still valuable to me, even though may not close the loop for some time.

Comment: Well sure, as and when you are able to do it, just post the solution to this question.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also don’t mind me asking, I know it is quite dumb of me but can you please link the forum section that you mentioned?

Comment: No problem at all, Valay: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards